# What is the proper name for the document with all the right answer of an exam?

Tags: synonyms

When a teacher builds an exam he usually has in a safe place a document with all the right answers for that exam.

What is the right name for this document?

Comment: "Key" is one term that is used, but I'm thinking there are others.

Comment: The ***Answer Key*** or as HotLicks says the key when context allows.

Comment: Scantron calls it "key" or "teacher's key": https://www.chaffey.edu/language_arts/mary/Scantron_Quick_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: @Jim, you can post this as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper name is an [answer key](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/answer_key).

> A textbook, section of a textbook, website, etc., that provides the solutions to mathematical problems, grammar exercises, etc.

Comment: What's the reference of your definition?

Answer (score 0):

It could also be called a cheat sheet if you are student taking a test and shouldn't be viewing it.

Comment: Answers should provide citations. Please edit your answer to include a link to a dictionary definition.